# Failure to restart puma after capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, puma

I'm trying to deploy a rails app from my machine to an aws linux ec2 using capistrano.

I used the `bundle exec cap production deploy` command and it actually deploys a new release to the server successfully but it fails to (re)start puma. At the puma restart phase I get this error (For privacy, I replaced the actual app name in the error with <app-name>):

```
01:23 puma:restart
      01 sudo /bin/systemctl restart puma_<app-name>_production
      01 Failed to restart puma_<app-name>_production.service: Unit puma_<app-name>_production.service not found.
      01
#<Thread:0x00007f93fb8d2700@/Users/sary/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
        12: from /Users/sary/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
        11: from /Users/sary/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
        10: from /Users/sary/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
         9: from /Users/sary/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-puma-f9801f6762d1/lib/capistrano/tasks/systemd.rake:105:in `block (3 levels) in eval_rakefile'
         8: from /Users/sary/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-puma-f9801f6762d1/lib/capistrano/puma/systemd.rb:55:in `execute_systemd'
         7: from /Users/sary/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/bundler/gems/capistrano-puma-f9801f6762d1/lib/capistrano/puma/systemd.rb:48:in `sudo_if_needed'
         6: from /Users/sary/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/capistrano-3.12.0/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:44:in `sudo'
         5: from /Users/sary/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:80:in `execute'
         4: from /Users/sary/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
         3: from /Users/sary/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `tap'
         2: from /Users/sary/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
         1: from /Users/sary/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:170:in `execute_command'
/Users/sary/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status=': sudo exit status: 5 (SSHKit::Command::Failed)
sudo stdout: Failed to restart puma_<app-name>_production.service: Unit puma_<app-name>_production.service not found.
sudo stderr: Nothing written
        1: from /Users/sary/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/sary/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing on host 54.78.252.112: sudo exit status: 5 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
sudo stdout: Failed to restart puma_<app-name>_production.service: Unit puma_<app-name>_production.service not found.
sudo stderr: Nothing written
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 54.78.252.112: sudo exit status: 5
sudo stdout: Failed to restart puma_<app-name>_production.service: Unit puma_<app-name>_production.service not found.
sudo stderr: Nothing written


Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: sudo exit status: 5
sudo stdout: Failed to restart puma_<app-name>_production.service: Unit puma_<app-name>_production.service not found.
sudo stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => puma:restart
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing on host 54.78.252.112: sudo exit status: 5
sudo stdout: Failed to restart puma_<app-name>_production.service: Unit puma_<app-name>_production.service not found.
sudo stderr: Nothing written


** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:
```

Disclaimer: I inherited this deployment process from a previous engineer so rails/puma/capistrano aren't my specialty.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It appears like you do not have a puma service unit file yet on your Production server. You can create one at, `/etc/systemd/system/puma_<app-name>_production.service`.

You should add a Unit entry into the service file. Refer to this, https://gist.github.com/arteezy/5d53d99f6ee617fae1f0db0576fdd418

Once you have created this. Next step is to test this service:

```
$ systemctl start puma_<app_name>_production.service 
$ systemctl status puma_<app_name>_production.service # Check status is running
```

In case the puma service doesn't start, thoroughly check the paths mentioned in your service file.

If this still persists, hope this unblocks you to make progress.